# For Each en Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, phpmyadmin, controller

soy nuevo en esto de la programacion y estoy tratando de entender como puedo hacer que mi slide(card, como quieran decirle) cicle pero con informacion de la base de datos de manera de no repetir tanto Html. Este es el codigo de mi LARAVEL. Gracias !

´´´

```
@foreach ($collection as $item)
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="hotel-item">
                                    <div class="radius-top">
                                        <img src="{{ asset('img/turismoCultural/teatro-gualeguaychu.png') }}" alt="" style="weight: 30%">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="title clearfix">
                                        <h4><b>Teatro Gualeguaychu</b></h4>
                                        <img src="img/ubicacion.png" alt="" style="color: black;">
                                        <h5 class="f-14 color-dark-2">Urquiza 705</h5><br>
                                        <img src="{{ asset('img/phone_logo.png')}}" alt="">
                                        <h5 class="f-14 color-dark-2">43-1757</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
```

´´´

Comment: Consultando a la base de datos, iterando la colección y mostrando los datos

Comment: podrias darme un ejemplo  por favor ? poniendo que cosa iria en el controlador y que cosa en el HTML

Comment: La documentación de Laravel es bien didáctica trata algo y cuando tengas dudas puntuales te apoyamos, te adelanto que la pregunta es casi seguro termine cerrada pues no demuestras algo de trabajo de tu parte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu controlador, necesitas hacer una consulta a tu base de datos, o simplemente generar la información que quieres enviar a tu vista.

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
function myFunction()
{
    $result= Tumodelo::where('active', 1)->get();

    return view('TuVista')->with($result);
}
```

Y en tu vista, a través de tu código html recorres tu información

```
@foreach($result as $data)
   <h1>{{$data->algo}}</h1>
@endforeach
```

Comment: perfecto, solo tengo una duda, como hago para mostrar la foto que yo quiero, porque eso me traeria todas las fotos y son muchas, o me equivoco ?

Comment: cierto, ya lo corregí

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda a los 2